# writeCharacteristic always returning false

Tags: android

Hello 'm trying to exchange data between android device and custom board with BLE module. And i have some troubles with characteristicsWrite() method on Android devices . In lover characteristicsWrite() method return true and then calls onCharacteristicsWrite() callback in BleGattCallback

Can any one help on the issue

```
 public void writeCommand(BluetoothGatt gatt,int bright_value) {
     if (bluetoothGatt != null) {
         List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices = gatt.getServices();
         for (int i = 0; i < gattServices.size(); i++) {
             String serviceUUID = gattServices.get(i).getUuid().toString();
             if (serviceUUID.equalsIgnoreCase(SERVICE_GUID)) {
                 List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = gattServices.get(i).getCharacteristics();
                 for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic :
                         gattCharacteristics) {
                     final String uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                     if (uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(TX_CHAR_GUID)) {
                         String jsonString = "{\"i\": 1, \"v\": 1, \"t\": 8, \"s\": \"dbri\", \"n\": "+ bright_value +"}";
                         byte[] payload = jsonString.getBytes();
                         writeCharacteristic(uuid, String.valueOf(gattCharacteristic.getUuid()),payload, BluetoothStatusCodes.SUCCESS);
                        /* gattCharacteristic.setValue(payload);
                         if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                             return;
                         }
                         Log.i("jyothi", "jyothi:" + jsonString);
                         gattCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
                         boolean writeStatus = gatt.writeCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);
                         Log.i("mtu", "writeStatus:" + writeStatus);*/
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }

public int writeCharacteristic(String serviceUuid,String characteristicUuid, byte[] value,int writeType) {
        UUID serviceid = null;
        UUID characteristicid = null;
        try {
            serviceid = UUID.fromString(serviceUuid);
            characteristicid = UUID.fromString(characteristicUuid);
            BluetoothGattService service = bluetoothGatt.getService(serviceid);
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(characteristicid);

            if (characteristic == null) {
                new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            if(!characteristic.setValue(value)) return writeType;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return writeType;
    }
```

Comment: **In lover characteristicsWrite() method return true and then calls onCharacteristicsWrite() callback** - If it returns true and then calls `onCharacteristicWrite`, then this is what it is supposed to do. I mean it is ok. But in the title you say that `writeCharacteristic` always returns false. Can you make it clear please?

Comment: boolean writeStatus = gatt.writeCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic); here 
I am getting false

Comment: You can use the new method overload https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#writeCharacteristic(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20byte[],%20int) which was added in Android 13 to get an integer as error code instead of a boolean, which is more helpful since it describes the error cause (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothStatusCodes). If `ERROR_GATT_WRITE_REQUEST_BUSY` is returned, you violate the API by writing a characteristic before the previous GATT operation has completed (callback has been called).

Comment: @Emil code updated please have a look

Comment: That code never even calls `writeCharacteristic` on the `BluetoothGatt` object.